# Select Option for children it is behaving weird when parent is selected Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am having an error during selecting the parent and its children on the select option.
The idea behind it is that I have for parent another select option and for the child another one.
I do have parent objects and as children nested objects which in my case are subCategory.

The problem it is that when the parent changes, the child it is empty and need to select on empty object that the list gets updated.

It is possible somehow that when parent is selected automatically show the children of the selected parent ?

Here is the code on stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujehrd?file=src/app/app.component.html

I have something like this.

```
<div class="col-md-12 pb-2">
<label>{{ "pagesInfo.categories" | translate }} </label>
      <select
      class="col-md-12 form-control-sm"
      [ngModel]="page?.categories"
      (ngModelChange)="showChildren($event)"
      required
    >
      <option
        *ngFor="let level of categoryService.categories"
        [ngValue]="level"
        [selected]="level"
        (change)="showChildren(level)"
      >
        {{ level.description | translate }}
      </option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 pb-2">
      <label>{{ "categories.subCategories.name" | translate }} </label>
      <select
      class="col-md-12 form-control-sm"

      [(ngModel)]="selectedChildren"
    >
   <ng-container>
      <option
        *ngFor="let subCat of selectedChildren"
        [ngValue]="subCat"
      >
        {{ subCat.description | translate }}
      </option>
    </ng-container>
    </select>
    </div>
```

This is my TS to show the children.

```
 selectedChildren = [];
 showChildren(event) {
    this.selectedChildren = [];
    this.selectedChildren.push(event.subCategories);
  }
```

And my categories looks like this.

```
export class Page {
  _id: string;
  name = "";
  slogan = "";
  description = "";
  categories: Categories[];
}

export interface Categories {
  description: string;
  subCategory?: [{
    name?: string,
    tags?: [{
        name: string
    }]
  }]
}
```

My service when I load the data.

```
  public categories = [];

  public getCategories() {
    this.categories = [
      { id: Categories.Businesses, description: "categories.Businesses.name",
        subCategories: [
        { id: BusinnesSubCategory.Advertising_Marketing, description: "categories.Businesses.Advertising_Marketing"},
        { id: BusinnesSubCategory.Agriculture, description: "categories.Businesses.Agriculture"}
] },
 { id: Categories.Community_Organization, description: "categories.Community_Organization.name",
        subCategories: [
          { id: CommunityOrganizationSubCategory.Armed_Forces, description: "categories.Community_Organization.Armed_Forces"},
          { id: CommunityOrganizationSubCategory.Charity_Organization, description: "categories.Community_Organization.Charity_Organization"}
]},

{ id: Categories.Interest, description: "categories.Interest.name",
      subCategories: [
        { id: InterestSubCategory.Literary_Arts, description: "categories.Interest.Literary_Arts"},
        { id: InterestSubCategory.Performance_Art, description: "categories.Interest.Performance_Art"},
```

Comment: are you trying to populate the subcategory according to parent category ?

Comment: @FaizalHussain The subcategory is or exist for each category.
But If there is a way to show subcategories of selected category without populating glad to see that.

Comment: did you try    this.selectedChildren = event.subCategories;  ( assign it rather than pushing it )

Comment: It seems it is working but weird I am getting error when I select parent or subCategory  **ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed**.
Later on I need to preselect the dropdowns what they values comes backend.

Comment: youre using selectedChildrenfor for looping and ngModel , use different variable for ngModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by Faizal, you're using `[(ngModel)]="selectedChildren"` for the child select.

`ngModel` directive is used for the *value* of the `<select>` - you don't need to provide the list as a "model" for the selection.

The best solution is to use a different property as the model:

```
public selectedChild = null


`[(ngModel)]="selectedChild"`
```

Also there's a problem where you're pushing the whole subcategories into the selection so it is then an array of arrays of subcategories. Just assign the subcatecories as the children array.

```
this.selectedChildren = event.subCategories
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ysodem?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcategory.service.ts